# Loopback Model Synchronisation

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have started do develop an API server for general use by multiple applications: 2 AngularJS Apps (frontend and backend) and Android App. Now I have a question: how to easily synchronize the models between all apps, if they are in different folders?

Comment: define "synchronize"

Comment: I will be using some auto form generator for models in angular and the main idea is that as soon as the attributes are added on the server they automatically paper in frontend.

Comment: If the models are identical in both apps, you could set up rsync or something to be triggered after you run the generator. What should you do about Android app - I have no idea. :)